# xamarin forms ios build fails after changed mac machine

Tags: xcode, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get the following error when building after changed the mac machine(I'm using VMWare and created new machine to use the latest OS version)

I copied the xcode project from old machine to the new one.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     2019-12-16 04:09:43.959 ibtoold[1526:26675] DEBUG: Added to
>   environment: {
>       TMPDIR = "/var/folders/xn/r2znrb712jl3558nqh0000gn/T/1AA1234D-4B58-5555-6665-52BC1709F584";
>   } 2019-12-16 04:09:45.057 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1549:27672]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ExpoUp.iOS/xxx/obj/iPhone/Release/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png
>
> 2019-12-16 04:09:45.076 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1549:27672]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ExpoUp.iOS/xxx/obj/iPhone/Release/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png

Comment: Delete the folder `bin` and `obj` both in share project and iOS project . Then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Did you try=>
 xcrun simctl delete unavailable   ----and----
 xcrun simctl erase all